# how to use case statements in CDbCriteria() of Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

how to use sql case statements in yii framework's CDbCritera()
e.g i have this query
      SELECT 
        CASE
         when userid is not null then userid
        end
      as USERID,
        CASE 
         when userid is not null then \'D\'
        end
      as H

if I do this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('case statement here');
modelname::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

it won't work, because addCondition is a 'WHERE' clause

if I use `$criteria->condition()` am getting this error

```
CDbCriteria and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "condition".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "[select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail)" property of [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) class.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = array(
    '(CASE ... END)',
    'column1',
    'column2'
)
modelname::model()->findAll($criteria);
```